# how to collapse npm dependency tree

Tags: npm

I'm looking for a way to collapse the npm dependency tree

This output isn't super easy to work with

```
npm ls -a
```

The text tree is helpful, but scrolling up every time I need see the parent isn't great.

Does anyone know of a GUI tool or some way to collapse nodes to make this easier?

Answer (score 0):

Can you plese try this and tell me whether it helped you

```
 npm ls  --depth=0
```

And about a graphical viewer i have to check